# Calculating distance between polygon and polyline

Tags: qgis, distance

I am trying to calculate the shortest distance between a multipolygon and multiLinestring.

The multiLinesting is composed of waterlines across the UK, and the multipolygon is of woodlands across the UK.

I wanted to calculate their shortest distance, whether the waterline runs through the woodland or besides it - What is the best way of doing it?

I have tried using `Grass v.distance` on QGis however, I Gert the following error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xb0' in position 919: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Have you tried ´join attributes by nearest`? If so, how does the output not suit your needs?

Comment: That is definitely a better improvement! thanks